# Is it possible to access /private/var/root/Media/DCIM/100APPLE on a non jailbroken phone?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to access /private/var/root/Media/DCIM/100APPLE through iphone app on a non jailbroken iphone. will apple allow to do this?

Answer (score 3):

No. It's not.

The **Apple way to do it** would be through an API to access that info. If there's no API, there's no access.